# Nested data results includes null values using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I do have a List(collection) containing Customer objects,and the customer class is defined as below, containng name and collection of Order, inturn order containing description and collection of orderdetail, and orderdetail has product and quantity.

How can I write a LINQ query to get a list of customers 
whose quantity is equal to 100 from a collection of Customer Object collection? I made a query (see below) the problem is, those orderDetail having null values is included. Any suggestions?

```
**Objects**

Customer { string Name; List<Order> OrderList;}

Order { string Desc; List<OrderDetail> OrderDetailList;}

OrderDetail { string Product; string Quantity; }


**Query**
 customer = ctx.Customer.Include(p=>p.Order)
               .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Order.Any(c=> c.OrderDetail
                                                      .Any(a=>a.Quantity==100)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to get a list of customers, but you use `SingleOrDefault` which only returns a single customer (if any). You need to use `Where`.

As for avoiding nulls you can just add a check for it inside the query (`.Where(a => a != null && ...)`).

Another issue is that your problem doesn't seem to be well defined.
Each customer has a list of orders and each order has a list of "details". So when you say you want to get a list of customers whose quantity is equal to 100, it's not clear: do you want all customers which have an order for which one of the product has a quantity of 100? Or maybe you want all customers which have an order for which the sum of quantities is 100?

For the first (one quantity equals 100) you can write:

```
customers = ctx.Customer.Include(p => p.Order).Where(x => 
  x.Order.Any(c => c.OrderDetail != null && c.OrderDetail.Any(
              a => a.Quantity == 100)));
```

For the second (sum quantities equal 100) you can use `Sum` and write:

```
customers = ctx.Customer.Include(p => p.Order).Where(x =>
  x.Order.Any(c => c.OrderDetail != null && c.OrderDetail.Sum(
              a => a.Quantity) == 100)));
```

One last thing you might want to check (though it wasn't part of your question). In your sample code you use `Include` which means you might had problems with unloaded references and that's why you added the `Include` (I'm guessing you use entity framework). So, it might be the case that the nulls you're encountering in OrderDetail is also a result of unloaded references and not real nulls (and if that's the case you should add `Include` for OrderDetail as well, or load the references some other way).